# SonarQube BitBucket Auth plugin allows any BitBucket user to login

Tags: git, oauth-2.0, sonarqube, bitbucket

Was able to get the BitBucket Authentication Plugin, [sonar-auth-bitbucket](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-auth-bitbucket),  working with my SonarQube Version 6.7 (build 33306) server and was so very happy until I noticed that apparently it will allow **any** BitBucket user to login as login as long as they have a BitBucket account. Which sort of defeats the purpose of setting up SSL and authentication as I only want users on my private BitBucket account to be able to access SonarQube.

Is there some sort of setting I am missing as I have configured it with oAuth for the private repository? But apparently as long as I have a BitBucket ID anyone can log in.

Am I missing something here as it seems odd to setup an oAuth configuration in a private BitBucket account only to let everyone on the planet be able to login?

Comment: any news on this one?

Comment: No news on this one but no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

sonar-auth-bitbucket previously (as of v1.0) did not support team restriction. Version 1.1 claims to support this. However, it requires SonarQube 7.2 or greater, and is not entirely bug-free at the time of writing.